# Creating native android application for a Wordpress website

Tags: android, wordpress, blogs

I want to create a native android application for a wordpress website. I want the user to be able to

view the blogs according to the categories.One approach I found is to use xml-rpc api which is

provided by Wordpress. With administrator rights it is working, but I would like to read blog

categories and posts without hardcoding administrator credentials for security reasons. 
Another approach I found is to use RSS feed parsing. But I'm not able to get through it properly. Is there any other alternative for doing this? Any suggestion or advice would really be helpful..

Comment: If you just want to read data, you can use `JSON API Plugin` without credentials.

Answer (score 0):

An other way you can explore is to use the [JSON API Plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/). I used it for a previous app, and the features provided are quite good to retrieve blog content. Anyway you retrieve data in a JSON file then you have to treat it. I used [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) library which provided simple features too.

Comment: I've installed and activated JSON API plugin but don't know how to get json format data from it and how to use it in my app. Is there any tutorial or a link that I could refer to??

Comment: Can you check that the plugin is active by calling `http://www.MYBLOG.com/api/get_recent_posts/` which is the only call configured in a fresh install.

Comment: Yes, I got the appropriate response. The plugin is active

Comment: Okay, it's great. The next step is to bind this JSON with Java object, so you have to use libs like Jackson. The only tuto refering to it I found is in french, but maybe you can translate it. [HERE](http://www.tutos-android.com/parsing-json-jackson-android)

Comment: Okay..I'm referring the tutorial. They have used this link "http://www.tutos-android.com/JSON/users.json" to parse the json file. What should I use in place of that so that I could get the data from my wordpress website?